# Проверить, входит ли хоть один день из периода в заданный месяц

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, sql

Привет.

Есть таблица Table (id, date1, date2). Как проверить, входит ли хоть один день из периода с date1 по date2 в заданный месяц (год тоже указан)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подразумевая, что Дата1 меньше Дата2:

Дата1 лежит в интервале < 1 числа следующего месяца, а Дата2 >= 1 заданного месяца.
Конкретика зачисит от используемой СУБД.

**Обновление**

Работать нужно с датами.
январь 2014:
первое число 2014/01/01 - переводите в тип даты.
Добавляете 1 месяц получаете 1 число следующего месяца.
Далее по алгоритму.

Comment: @msi, например, дата1 = 01.01.2013, дата2 = 01.01.2015
нас интересует январь 2014.
вот тут я уперся, как проверять корректно? ведь этот период удовлетворяет нашим условиям, но как условие записать в where

Comment: Работать нужно с датами.
январь 2014:
первое число 2014/01/01 - переводите в тип даты.
Добавляете 1 месяц получаете 1 число следующего месяца.
Далее по алгоритму.